# NestJS with language change based on URL

Tags: internationalization, nestjs

I'm trying to do a language change with NestJS. Example,
if user type in URL:

- [www.blabla.com/en](http://www.blabla.com/en) <-- text in the page will show english
- [www.blabla.com/cn](http://www.blabla.com/cn) <-- text in the page will display in chinese font
- [www.blabla.com/jp](http://www.blabla.com/jp) <-- text in the page will display in japan font

I read about i18n but not sure how is the logic to do in NestJS. Please kindly help. Thank you.

Comment: have you search on integrations of i18n with nestjs in nodejs community?

Comment: oh using i18n? Thank you, let me try to find that